# Set the Height of Candle Bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In trading view pine script, how to set the height of candle bar, which 30% smaller of the 1st/3rd candle bar ?

Sample image:
[image]

Refer script from [rmunoz](https://www.tradingview.com/script/BL8j8idt-Evening-Morning-Star-Pattern/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Candle sizes depend on open/close (body) and high/low (wick) prices. These are calculated and displayed automatically by Tradingview.

If you want to draw your own candles and set their heights to whatever you want, you can use the `plotcandle()` function.

> plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title, color, wickcolor, editable,
> show_last, bordercolor, display) → void